# How to run a rails migration as sql file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My database admins do not want to control access to any drop/alter/create commands.  Is there anyway to emulate what rails is doing to the schema migrations table and convert the migrations themselves in a reliable way to fake rails out into thinking it has been ran and also handle rollbacks?  They want to run this from their end of course.  I have seen a few suggestions, but no wholistic approach. Perhaps the answer is it really shouldn't be done, which is what I think right now as I believe it will just cause headaches and unreliability down the road.

Comment: shouldn't be done is definitively a good answer... i'm actually not sure if you even need to fake anything. you can just have the changes applied to the database, structure dump from production, voila, no need for migrations.

Comment: So you are suggesting dump the structure from a lower environment where I am using migrations and have that sql applied?  What about the schema migrations table update?  Surely that would need fudged since my schema.db file will think there is a pending migration otherwise?

Comment: no, i'm suggesting that after your dba has applied the schema changes, you run rake db:schema:dump on production.

Comment: I see.  Not sure that would work since my dev and qa environments would be kept up to date through one process, then reapplied from a separate process that prod has used, then dumped.  The fact there haven't been answers on this thread of someone having to do this should be a sign I guess :(

Comment: it's doable, but it's not "the rails way"

Comment: Agreed...but maybe nothing I can do about it. :(